# Random VPN Client unable to contact the security gateway

Tags: cisco-vpn

We are issuing new Win764bit Enterprise laptops with the Cisco VPN Client Version 5.0.0.07.0290 installed on it. We are importing a pcf file from a CD given to us by our security group into it before releasing.

Around 10% of the clients when connecting take around 30 seconds to attempt to connect to the security gateway. Sometimes they ask for a username and password and then fail, or other times they will just fail directly.

The error message is always "Secure VPN Connection terminated locally by the client. Reason 412: The remote peer is no longer responding."

On the other 90% of the laptops there is no issue and the connect and prompt for authentication almost instantly. The laptop models and builds are identical and can be plugged into the same network and reproduce the either working or not working behavior.

I am at my wits end here with this, thoughts?

Comment: If you look in the profiles subfolder where the client is installed are there any files that aren't pcf?

Comment: There are two files the .pcf and a .pcf.use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like either one of the two issues is happening.

- The account you are logged on as doesn't have write permissions to the `profiles` folder.
- The files in that directory are read-only.

You shouldn't be seeing the `.use` file unless you are connected.

Comment: So if I delete the .use file it comes back right away.

Comment: Facepalm here, the files were set read only! and now it connects. Why are they readonly?

Comment: No idea. They shouldn't be.

Answer (score 1):

If the system is Windows 7:

1. Stop the Cisco VPN Client software.
2. Delete the `..\Cisco Systems\VPN Client\vpnclient.ini` file.
3. Make the `..\Cisco Systems\VPN Client\Profiles\ *.pcf` files NOT read only.
4. Uncheck any associated Compatibility modes on start short cut.
5. Start the program and all should be well.

(Start shortcut may have to be run in administrator mode, depending on user security. Also, be sure to backup your .pcf files in another folder as they may be changed by the system or other users. If you re-install Cisco VPN then delete all folders as well.)